# Center two columns in bootsrap 4

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have two column and I want to center them , in boostrap 3 it was imple using push and pull in boostrap 4 its different and I cant figure out .

here is what i have .

```
 <div class="col-sm bg-success">1 </div>
      <div class="col-sm bg-warning">2 </div>
    </div>
```

I want these two divs to be centered like this.

[image]

what do I need to change to get the result I want to?

Comment: What percentage of a row do those 2 columns take? So many ways to center them with bootstrap 4. You can wrap them in a div with `max-width` and css class `mx-auto`: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/utilities/spacing/#horizontal-centering

Comment: both of them should have col-sm-4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `offset-` class to get what you want.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-4 offset-sm-2 bg-success">
          1
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-4 bg-warning">
          2
      </div>
  </div>  
</div>
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/aq9Laaew/72786/

Comment: Thanks David in desktop looks as I expected, but in mobile loks like this https://ibb.co/g3dUGd, what do I need to change to be rensponsive , as you can see here the second form is pushed left , i want to be centered as calendar?

Comment: It's hard to guess by looking at your pictures. There are many factors that can cause the issue. Is it possible to post up the HTML structure as well as other styles you applied?

Comment: Yeah here is fiddle for it : https://jsfiddle.net/Mwanitete/w69jfyv1/2/

Comment: I can only tell your HTML structure and the scss file from your fiddle. It didn't run. Anyway, try taking out the `width: 100%;` from `about-booking` css class. There are margins on the `row` class and its columns. Setting the width to 100% on a row with push it to the left, ignoring the left margin.

Comment: hii david can you check this thread? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51210526/angular-6-proper-implementation-of-controlvalueaccessor

Answer (score 2):

Add them to a `row` that has `justify-content-center`

```
<div class="row justify-content-center">
    <div class="col-4 bg-success">1 </div>
    <div class="col-4 bg-warning">2 </div>
</div>
```

Optionally, add `mr-*` to the first column's classes, where `*` indicates the space to add between them.

https://codepen.io/tentacular261/pen/XYLKMw

Comment: Thanks mical in desktop looks as I expected, but in mobile loks like this https://ibb.co/g3dUGd , what do I need to change to be rensponsive , as you can see here the second form is pushed left , i want to be centered as calendar?

Comment: You can add a breakpoint to the margin class `mr-*-*`, where the first `*` is xs, sm, md, lg, and where the second `*` is the amount of space you chose. `mr-sm-1` I think should give you what you want.